# XSL manually selecting child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, select

Stupid question here. Got total brain-lock today.

I want to manually select a specific child node from xml. 
EG.

```
    <somenode>
         <somechild>Something</somechild>
         <somechild>Something else</somechild>
         <somechild>Something new</somechild>
         <somechild>Something old</somechild>
         <somechild>Something borrowed</somechild>
         <somechild>Something green ha ha</somechild>
    </somenode>
```

I know I can use

```
    <xsl:for-each select=
```

to select all of them.
But how, for example, can I just select node 2 using xsl 1.0 please?

I know its a pretty basic question, and I should know the answer. Just having a bad day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/somenode/somechild[2]"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-PredicateExpr

> /doc/chapter[5]/section[2] selects the second section of the fifth chapter of the doc

So, for your example

`/somenode/somechild[2]`

Comment: Please, avoid giving w3schools as an authoritative source. Read more here: http://w3fools.com

Comment: In this case it was the first google hit, and correct for the question. In future I'll look for another reference.

Comment: @_ptomli: The only normative reference is the original W3C specification. Anything else is just how someone interpretes it.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev OK, and it's not *hugely* obtuse, I'll update the answer